# Add an :after to only <p> that contain an <img>

Tags: html, css

I'm facing a issue, and trying to solve it using only CSS.

Here is my html

```
<body>
    <p>empty</p>
    <p><img src="/"></p>
    <p><img src="/"></p>
    <p>empty</p>
</body>
```

And my CSS

```
body {
    counter-reset: my-sec-counter;
}
p {
    position: relative;
}
p:after {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 17px;
    top: -15px;
    right: -15px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    transition: .1s;
    counter-increment: my-sec-counter;
    content: "#" counter(my-sec-counter);
    color: #fff;
    border: 3px solid white;
    background-color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

But I'd like to display an `after` element only if `p` contains an `img`. I tried `img ~ p:after` but doesn't work.

Any help?

Comment: Try p img:after {}

Comment: Yes, it's what I started from, but after elements don't work with img tags

Comment: @Keith – That will select the `::after` pseudo-element of the image which (a) isn't what is asked for and (b) won't do anything because images are replaced elements and can't have `::after` content.

Comment: @Quentin Not sure what you're talking about, <img> can have pseudo elements added to it https://jsfiddle.net/Lbqfe20h/ . As for what he's asking, if there is an <img> tag after <p> then p img:after will certainly work

Comment: you can use jQuery as well. Pseudo doesn't work on img element $('img[src=""]').parents().addClass('pseudoSelector');

Comment: @Artik if the other `p` tags are really empty you code just use `p:not(:empty):after {` but I assume that is not the case?

Comment: @circa1983 Unfotunately  it's not empty, but it's only text content. I'l try anyway